# Bash not loading inputrc automatically

Tags: bash, readline

No matter what I try I can't get bash to load my `~/.inputrc` file. The most minimal example I have tested is getting rid of my `~/.bashrc` and then having a single line in my `~/.inputrc` with

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Even so, I can't tab complete without case sensitivity.

If I simply do `bind -f ~/.inputrc`, then the setting is loaded.

Am I missing something? Isn't it supposed to be loaded automatically? I am using Fedora with bash 4.4.23 and readline 7.0.

Comment: Try disabling the programmable completion with `shopt -u progcomp`.

Comment: Do you have an INPUTRC environment variable set?  If you do it would attempt to use the filename specified rather than taking the default. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/bind.c#n920

Comment: @icarus You nailed it! I'll accept your answer if you want to make it a full one. I had set `INPUTRC` to `~/.config/inputrc` (trying to declutter my `HOME` directory) but somehow forgot about that and had fallen back to editing `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bash` uses the `readline` library to do interactive input processing. This library is responsible for reading the initialization file. By default this is `~/.inputrc`, but an `INPUTRC` environment variable provides an override.

So if the ~/.inputrc file is not processed, check for a INPUTRC variable.

The next thing to check is that the lines being added are **not** within a conditional.